# Google Maps show hide markers by active icons

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hello I'm using google maps API. I have some buttons and I want to show the active markers. If i will click on the image with restaurants then to show me all the markers with the restaurants and hide the others.. I have here the code i tried

```
  var customIcons = {
            restaurant: {
                icon: 'img/homepage/screen_3/map_pins/restaurante.png'
            },


            shopping: {
                icon: 'img/homepage/screen_3/map_pins/shopping.png'
            },

            spa: {
                icon: 'img/homepage/screen_3/map_pins//spa-&-aquapark.png'
            }

        };


        var markerGroups = {
            "restaurant": [],

            "shopping": [],

            "spa": []
        };



        function load() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.059516, 21.947613),
                zoom: 13,
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            });
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            downloadUrl("googlemaps/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function (data) {
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var id_marker = markers[i].getAttribute("id_marker");
                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                    var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                    var img = markers[i].getAttribute("img");
                    var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
                    var schedule = markers[i].getAttribute("schedule");
                    var link = markers[i].getAttribute("link");
                    document.getElementById('categorii').src = img;
                    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                    bounds.extend(point);
                    var html = "<u class='title-google-maps'>" + name + "</u> <p class='google-maps'>" + category + "</p>" + address + "<p class='google-maps'>" + phone + "</p>" + "<p class='google-maps-2'>" + schedule + "</p>" + link;
                    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: icon.icon,
                        id_marker: id_marker,
                        image: img,
                        type: type

                    });

                    if (!markerGroups[type])
                        markerGroups[type] = [];
                    markerGroups[type].push(marker);
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

                }
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                toggleGroup("spa");

            });

        }



        function toggleGroup(type) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
                var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
                if (!marker.getVisible()) {

                    marker.setVisible(true);


                } else {

                    marker.setVisible(false);

                }

            }
        }


        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);


                document.getElementById('categorii').src = marker.image;

            });
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                    new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {
        }

        //]]>

    </script>
```

And here is the HTML code

```
<section id="about">

        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding"><img class="img-responsive image-locations" id="categorii" src=""></div>

        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding google-maps-style">
            <div id="map" style="left:0;top:0;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-md-12 categ-icons">

                <img onclick="toggleGroup('spa')"  class="selector-icon spa img-responsive loc_sel" style="padding:1em;" src="img/homepage/screen_3/icon_selector/spa-aquapark-icon-inactiv.png" data-on-src="img/homepage/screen_3/icon_selector/spa-aquapark-icon-activ.png"/>

                <img onclick="toggleGroup('shopping')"  class="selector-icon shopping img-responsive loc_sel" style="padding:1em;" src="img/homepage/screen_3/icon_selector/shopping-inactiv.png" data-on-src="img/homepage/screen_3/icon_selector/shopping-activ.png"/>


                <img onclick="toggleGroup('restaurant')"  class="selector-icon restaurante img-responsive loc_sel" style="padding:1em;" src="img/homepage/screen_3/icon_selector/restaurante-inactiv.png" data-on-src="img/homepage/screen_3/icon_selector/restaurante-activ.png"/>



            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console when firing toggleGroup?

Comment: No errors, but that's not what I want

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: You might want to add custom details in your marker like for your case `businessType`:"spa, shopping, restaurant". Then creating a filtering function that will check the image you click and the `businessType` of the marker match make the marker visible if not hide the marker. For a code implementation see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35760099/5995040).